# ajax/javascript not working in ie

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im pretty much a newb when it comes to ajax and javascript :/.. This code works in chrome and firefox.. but Ie just has to mess everything up.. I searched for a bit and could not find any explanations as to why this would not work.

```
<div id="adsdiv"><div id="zcaptcha"></div></div>
<div id="divid"></div>

 <script>

   $("#zcaptcha").bind("correct", function(){
   document.getElementById("adsdiv").style.display = "none" ;

  setInterval(function(){

   jQuery("#divid").load('test.php',
    function(response, status, xhr) {

        if (status == "error") {
        jQuery("#divid").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
  }, 100);

     });

  </script>
```

Comment: And what is triggering the "correct" event ?

Comment: What happens in IE? Can you see the HTTP request arriving at your server? What does the IE debug tools say? Are there errors on the JS Console? Can you see the request being sent in the Net tab of the developer tools?

Comment: Seriously?  You're trying to reload content every 0.1 sec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is probably caching the content, thus you never get new content.  You can break the cache by using this:

```
jQuery("#divid").load('test.php?' + Math.random(),
```

---

Also, are you seriously trying to run this every 0.1 sec?